# intercept back/home buttons from within a custom software keyboard

Tags: android, ime

I would like to create an IME (subclassing InputMethodService) that is able to intercept the back button press by itself. I don't want to subclass the editText and intercept the back button outside the IME, before it is processed by the IME.
my IME must be able to do it by itself. 
Actually, I would prefer not to show at all the navigation bar when the soft keyboard is on, but after several searches it seems that is not possible (of course I have already made the app working in SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY modality, so when soft keyboard hides, the navigation bar disappear)
thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, the BACK button does not pass through the IME. It is displayed by the system to dismiss the IME. Similarly, the HOME button does not pass through the IME. Bear in mind that on Android 10+ devices (and devices from some manufacturers), there may not be HOME or BACK buttons to intercept -- those are handled by system gestures.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I would like to replay what is done by talkback service (first press playback button label, double tap "execute" the button). there, when I tap the back button I hear back, and when I double tap it, it removes the soft keyboard. my IME is for blind users, and i have to prevent unwanted back presses. I would like my IME to be able to internally manage it, rather then relying on edittext container. otherwise I will add an empty row between nav bar and last valid row.

Comment: TalkBack is either part of the OS or is an `AccessibilityService`. You might be able to achieve your objective by having both an `AccessibilityService` and an IME.